# Passing list of values to django view via jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to pass a list of numeric values (ids) from one web page to another with jQuery ajax call. I can't figure out how to pass and read all the values in the list. I can successfully post and read 1 value but not multiple values. Here is what I have so far:

**jQuery:**

```
var postUrl = "http://localhost:8000/ingredients/";
$('li').click(function(){
    values = [1, 2];
    $.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'terid': values},
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('#ingredients').append(result);
            }
    });       
});
```

**/ingredients/ view:**

```
def ingredients(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        ourid = request.POST.get('terid', False)
        ingredients = Ingredience.objects.filter(food__id__in=ourid)
        t = get_template('ingredients.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'ingredients': ingredients,}))
        return HttpResponse(html)
    else:
        html = '<p>This is not ajax</p>'      
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

With Firebug I can see that POST contains both ids but probably in the wrong format (terid=1&terid=2). So my ingredients view picks up only terid=2. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I need the ourid variable pass values [1, 2] to the filter in the ingredients view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution to my original problem. Posting it here as an answer, hopefully it helps somebody.

**jQuery:**

```
var postUrl = "http://localhost:8000/ingredients/";
$('li').click(function(){
    values = [1, 2];
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(values);
    $.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonText,
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('#ingredients').append(result);
            }
    });       
});
```

**/ingredients/ view:**

```
def ingredients(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        ourid = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
        ingredients = Ingredience.objects.filter(food__id__in=ourid)
        t = get_template('ingredients.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'ingredients': ingredients,}))
        return HttpResponse(html)
    else:
        html = '<p>This is not ajax</p>'      
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Just an FYI - some older browsers don't have a JSON library built-in. You *might* be better off using `$.serialize` rather than `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 49):

You can access this array by **request.POST.getlist('terid[]')** in the view

in javascript:

```
$.post(postUrl, {terid: values}, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

in view.py:

```
request.POST.getlist('terid[]')
```

It works perfect for me.

Comment: `selected = request.GET.getlist[‌​'selected[]'] TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'  `I get this error... But i have an array of stings like ["one","two","three"‌​] and am using a `GET` request...

Comment: This works, but... why do you need `[]`? The django docs don't reference it at all https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.update

Comment: Extremely helpful and still relevant after 8 years!

Answer (score 3):

This part is your problem:

```
ourid = request.POST.get('terid', False)
ingredients = Ingredience.objects.filter(food__id__in=ourid)
```

You need to deserialize the JSON string.

```
import json
ourid = json.loads(request.POST.get('terid'))
```

Comment: When I do that I'm getting this error in the ajax callback: TypeError at /ingredients/
'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are setting the array to string here

```
data: {'terid': values},
```

It should be

```
data: {terid: values}
```

Comment: Still only the second value is picked up (terid=2).

Comment: Javascript doesn't care if you use quotations or not in modifying object attributes or dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending data like this:

```
   data: values;
```