# How can I pass a list of values from a django template to a django view function?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a django template viewreports.html which prints some results based on calculation done in a view function view_reports. But I have added a button to download csv to the template. Upon clicking the button I want to pass the result values from viewreports.html to another view function getcsvreport where the csv is generated. I'm unable to pass lists through the url. Can someone explain how I can pass multiple variables(some of them lists) from a template to a view function(through the url or any other method)??

Comment: I would use ajax for this.
See this question: [Passing list of values to django view via jquery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176594/passing-list-of-values-to-django-view-via-jquery-ajax-call/11176647)

Comment: I would have used the same view with an optional `format` kwarg/request param...

If it is csv return a CSV file, else return the html response

Comment: Also depending on your frontend, there are lot of javascript libraries that allow you to export data to csv